# Alias with dot in Input decorator in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to use an alias with dot in Input in Angular as follows;

```
@Input(‘attr.aria-label’) ariaLabel;
```

However, it doesn’t work. When I change it to aria-label and use a static text in template, it works fine. But I need to use a dynamic text, so I have to use attr.aria-label in the template. And in directive, I need to get this value using Input decorator. Is there anyway to use an alias with a dot or dash in Input decorator?

Comment: Using aliases is [not a good idea](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-13)

Comment: This does work, [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruc6nk)